# LiveValidation with the jQuery DatePicker

Tags: javascript, validation, livevalidation

I'm currently using the [LiveValidation](http://livevalidation.com) library on a field that uses the jQuery UI datepicker.

```
var expiry = new LiveValidation('expiry_date');
expiry.add( Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: "Date Required." } );
```

Unfortunately, after selecting a date, `LiveValidation` still thinks the field is empty and shows a validation error.

If I click inside the field and click away, the field is then valid.

Any tips on getting LiveValidation to detect that there is actually content in the date field?

Comment: Try [Ideal Forms](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/), it has live validation and jquery UI datepicker support built-in.

Comment: Cool! I'm the developer of that plugin so if you got problems I'm around StackOverflow.

Comment: hey @elclanrs, i m not anle to find ur http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/... is it replaced? plz help me out!

Answer (score 0):

While Defining js Datepicker on the field, mention
`onClose: function () { this.focus(); }`,that automatically gets captured by `LiveValidation`.

```
$('#expiry_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',                 
    onClose: function () { this.focus(); }
});
```