# CFWheels DatePicker Plugin and LiveValidation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, cfwheels, livevalidation

I'm using the DatePicker plugin for CFWheels (https://github.com/chapmandu/datepicker-cfwheels-plugin) along with LiveValidation (http://livevalidation.com/) to validate my forms.
The problem I'm having is when validating for Presence of my date text field, the error message pops up even if I selected a date. If I re-click the date text field again then the error message goes away.

```
var shipmentdate = new LiveValidation("shipmentdate");
    shipmentdate.add(Validate.Presence);
```

Seems like when I click to choose a date in the calendar box, since the element loses focus, it immediately validates which is probably why the error message comes up.
Since the selected date text gets filled after the element already lost focus, it doesn't re-validate to remove the error message. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
If possible, I don't really want to have to dig into the CFWheels DatePicker plugin and change things.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a related question recommended using a different client-side validator that supports the datepicker:
 [LiveValidation with the jQuery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814315/livevalidation-with-the-jquery-datepicker)

You may be able to fiddle with `focus`, and `blur` events for either the datepicker or the LiveValidation plugin to avoid triggering validation on date fields while using the datepicker. I don't have enough experience (or time) to write code for you, but you'll need to dig into this one unfortunately.